# Error calling postText from AWS lambda : There is no alias named devbotalias for the bot named devbot. Choose another alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Tried a lot of bits haven't find anything specific to solve this issue.

Complete Error ==>
2022-03-29T12:38:37.112Z    d6ccd7e5-71fc-4be2-834b-636790e14bfe    INFO    NotFoundException: There is no alias named devbotalias for the bot named devbot. Choose another alias.
at Object.extractError(/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:49:8)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12) {
code: 'NotFoundException',
time: 2022-03-29T12:38:37.074Z,
requestId: '79582f86-d5c4-47cf-9d58-ec3bea6ad9dc',
statusCode: 404,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 9.123462593662325

Code that is calling the Lex ==>

```
    const  {LexRuntimeServiceClient, PostTextCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service")
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const creds = new AWS.Credentials({
  accessKeyId: '<accessKeyId>', secretAccessKey: '<secretAccessKey>'
});
const client = new LexRuntimeServiceClient({ credentials: creds, region: "us-east-1" });
// async/await.
const params ={
    botAlias: 'devbotalias',
    botName: 'devbot',
    inputText: "Book",
    userId: "lexUserId",
    sessionAttributes: {
        }
    };
const command = new PostTextCommand(params);
// async/await.
try {
  const data = await client.send(command);
  // process data.
} catch (error) {
  // error handling.
} finally {
  // finally.
}
```

[permission to call lex from lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMsxc.png)

[Available aliases for my bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Fwi.png)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using the Lex V1 Javascript SDK to invoke a Lex V2 bot.

You need to make use of the Lex V2 Javascript SDK. Please see the link below to the documentation for the V2 client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lex-runtime-v2/index.html

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer if it worked for you.